# Randomised ramp-up time in JMETER?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there anyway to randomised ramp-up in JMeter? I want to randomized ramp-up time for my JMX script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function in Ramp Up Period field (seconds)

For example to random between 1-100 seconds:

```
${__Random(1,100,)}
```

> The random function returns a random number that lies between the given min and max values.

You can also get dynamic value from property using [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function

> Define the property value:
>
> ```
> jmeter -Jgroup1.threads=7 -Jhostname1=www.realhost.edu
> ```
>
> Fetch the values:
>
> ```
> ${__P(group1.threads)} -
> ```
>
> return the value of group1.threads

Comment: Thanks, Working fine now using __Random function